# Error with creating new route with total.js

Tags: node.js, total.js

I have the following problem with totals.js.When I try to add new route I get the following error:

> The controller's route does not define any schema.
>   (http://0.0.0.0:8000/****/****/****/1)

I have added this method to the schema with schema.addWorkflow method but it looks like this doesn`t work.

Comment: I need to see your code. Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: I can`t give you any code because of privacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error when you try to use schema's methods in controller (such as $get, $query, $save, etc.) but haven't added Schema name flag to the route definition

```
F.route('/routename', handler, ['*SchemaName']);
```

The flag `*SchemaName` tells the framework that you want to work with schema you defined using `NEWSCHEMA('SchemaName')...`

See documentation [here](https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~Framework~F.route~(schemas))